# what is the brocha on a young nut in its shell?

Tags: food, blessing

Young nuts are eaten together with their shells because they are soft and edible. What is the brocha on such a food?

Comment: Can you be more specific. Like what type of nut are you talking about?

Answer (score 1):

jutky was on the right path.

An adult nut in its' shell - Ha-aytz

A young nut in its shell- If the nut is usually eaten unripe, then it would be a Ha-aytz, because this is considered the normal way to eat the "fruit". However, if the nut is not usually eaten unripe, then the nut is not yet a fruit, so the brocha is Ha-adamah.

Shells and peels that the fruit can live without and are  eaten alone (eg. caper shell)- Ha-adamah
peels that the fruit would die without and are not normally eaten (eg. orange peel)- Shehakol

mostly Bruchos 36a+b
(ripe fruit is in Beruchos somewhere, but I can't find it)

Answer (score 0):

If it is way of eating nuts (דרך אכילה) then it should be "פרי העץ".

Or do you want to eat the shell without the nut itself?

Comment: @jutky i dont believe this is correct, please state your source